# Oldish (at least 15 years) children's book about a little creepy girl going to normal school for the first time?

Tags: identification-request

I only vaguely remember this but I know it wasn't a dream because my mom helped me read out loud with it. I only remember some details but I know it had some art in it, it had an Addams family vibe to it, the little girl was raised by spiders? or ghosts? or something similar? And one of the books was about her first day at a real school with normal kids?

And all I remember is that since she was raised like "goth" and creepy she didn't interact with anyone very well because everyone thought she was scary but I think she also thought they were scary? and I know there were lots of "scary" puns like "scream cheese". I'm so sorry I know this isn't a lot of detail but that was a long time ago when I read it.

Also I vaguely remember most of the color used only being grey and purple.

Comment: You could go over our [guidance for ID questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to see if it makes you remember anything else about the book. In particular, what was the language of the story?

Comment: You might want to reword the title, because "normal school" has a special meaning which you probably didn't intend. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_school

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a book based on the Discovery Kids show "Growing Up Creepie," 2006-2008?  Though I can't find a book, the story details match your description. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growing_Up_Creepie):

> As told in the opening introduction and in the episode "Creepie Crawling", Creepie was an infant left on the doorstep of the Dweezwold Mansion, which is home to a family of various insects. The family took her in and raised her as one of their own. She must now adjust to a life surrounded by a society of insectophobic humans as she attends Middlington Middle School and keeps her home life secret in order to protect both herself and her family."  Images show a predominately black and purple color scheme.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please could you add a little more detail to this answer, in order to help people find out about this show and whether or not it fits the question?

Comment: Edits were made.  Thank you!